# What concerns should i have about moving into a 100-year-old nj farmhouse?

Tags: electrical, flooring

The house was lived in and well-kept up til 5 years ago when my grandfather passed away.

There's no three-prong outlets except in the kitchen; i have a gaming pc pulling 750 watts or so, plus assorted other computers,  guitar amps, etc.

I plan to test the water, paint and dust for lead. (I've got a five-year-old.)

A recent radiator leak damaged the wall (cosmetically) and a dozen floorboards buckled, rising or sinking by an inch.

We'll be installing new smoke & carbon monoxide detectors too.

There's a well, barns in disrepair, railroad tracks, woods, rusting cars...

Anyone have any suggestions or advice? I'm mainly concerned with the safety of the house as opposed to the surrounding area (that's later!) All insights appreciated.

Comment: This is more like stating the obvious, rather than insightful, but old houses are great. Typically underinsulated, so the heating might be h3ll, but... (attic insulation might be "low hanging fruit"). I'd find a good heating guy to evaluate your setup. I'd put GFCI outlets anywhere near water. If it's knob and tube wiring, either leave it alone or rip it all out. Don't go halfway. Don't know about your area, but I'd consider a radon test if there was any possibility. If you swap the toilets for new low-flow ones, be aware that old lead flanges/cast pipe can be horrible to work on. Good luck!

Comment: First and foremost, I'd get a cover with a lock on the well, or change your kid's name to Jessica.

Answer (score 3):

If it's painted and that old, there's **going to be lead** paint, lead window putty, etc.

You'll not "really" want to to but really should investigate the septic arrangements, and get whatever it is pumped out and inspected. Water testing should include things other than lead (with the prime one being coliform bacteria, the most basic well-water test.)

Any old house will keep you from getting bored; there's always more to fix than you have time (and usually also money) for.

You'll probably end up replacing the electric wholesale, eventually. When you do, remember to run network wiring (or better yet, conduits for network wiring, since it tends to change over time, and being able to pull it out and replace it is golden.)

Rusty cars can usually be vanished with a call to the scrapyard - you might even get $50. Unless they are something with value to a collector (even in rusty condition,) that's probably the right call.

Comment: I would not be concerned about lead.  The daughter is 5... tell her not to chew on the paint.

Comment: I don't know if the comment above about chewing was a joke, but lead paint chips and dust are a serious problem.